# output of fixture in params in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I sat down to better learn py.test today and found the site with the documentation is down (pytest.org) so I appologize if the answer to this question is found there.

What I want to do is pass the output of two fixtures to a parametrize, like so:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def make_1():
    return 1

@pytest.fixture()
def make_2():
    return 2

@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', [make_1, make_2])
def test_main(arg):
    assert isinstance(arg, int)
```

but the tests fail because rather than assigning the outputs of the fixtures to the parameter "arg" the fixtures (functions) themselves are passed.

How can I parametrize the outputs of various fixtures in this way?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make `make_1` a regular function - does it need to be a fixture because it uses other fixtures or something?

Comment: You can't use fixtue in parametrization. https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349/using-fixtures-in-pytestmarkparametrize

Comment: This is also a very usable workaround: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349#issuecomment-189370273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this [ugly/massive hack] do the trick? I appreciate it's far from ideal - I don't know if there's a way to create a lazy-evaluated fixture that would let you do what you're trying to do.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def make_1():
    return 1

@pytest.fixture
def make_2():
    return 2

@pytest.fixture
def all_makes(make_1, make_2):
    return (make_1, make_2)

def _test_thing(make):
    # Run your test
    pass

def test_main(all_makes):
    for make in all_makes:
        try:
            _test_thing(make)
        except AssertionError:
            print "Failed for make {}".format(make)
            raise
```

A probably better alternative might be to parameterize the fixture itself (if possible) - ref the docs: https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-a-fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def make(request):
    return request.param

def test_make(make):
    # Run your test
    pass
```

If your different 'make' fixtures are super-different, you could have something like:

```
def build_make_1():
    return 1

def build_make_2():
    return 2

@pytest.fixture(params=[build_make_1, build_make_2])
def make(request):
    return request.param()

def test_make(make):
    # Run your test
    pass
```

Comment: Yes, using a fixture to call functions as in your last example should work fine, and writing one extra fixture to collect and call the functions isn't a big deal. Thanks for the answer! I also checked if scope="module" on the make fixture would still only call each of the functions once even if there are multiple tests that use them and it seems to.